# Getting rgb values from an image with different colors

Tags: php, image, argb

The code below (mostly from here) will create text in the color of the image as long as the image is a solid color. I want to be able to create the text when the image is not one color, like if it was the image of a brick where the surface has different, random, colors. I found some code here where each pixel of the source can be read in but then it merges those and that doesn't give a true reproduction. Is this possible>

```
    $im = imagecreatefrompng('green.png');
    $rgb = imagecolorat($im, 4,4);
    $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
    $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
    $b = $rgb & 0xFF;

    echo '<div style="font-size:60px;color:rgb(' .$r .','.$g.','.$b.')">Text in color of the Image</div>';
```

Comment: You want to write in red on red images? How will that be useful?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of one sample, I took 10 samples and averaged the color. You can try with even more samples.

```
        <?php 
    $im = imagecreatefrompng('images/green.png');

    $width = imagesx($im);
    $height = imagesy($im);        

    $hpart = round($width/5);  // divide image in five columns
    $vpart = round($height/2); // divide image in two rows


    $r = 0;
    $g = 0;
    $b = 0;

    $rarr = array();
    $garr = array();
    $barr = array();


    for($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
        $sampleh = round($hpart/2) + ($hpart*$i);
        $samplev = round($vpart/2);

        $rgb = imagecolorat($im, $sampleh,$samplev);
        $r += ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
        $g += ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
        $b += $rgb & 0xFF;        

        $rarr[] = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
        $garr[] = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
        $barr[] = $rgb & 0xFF;

    }

    for($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
        $sampleh = round($hpart/2) + ($hpart*$i);
        $samplev = round($vpart/2) + $vpart;

        $rgb = imagecolorat($im, $sampleh,$samplev);
        $r += ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
        $g += ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
        $b += $rgb & 0xFF;     

        $rarr[] = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
        $garr[] = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
        $barr[] = $rgb & 0xFF;            

    }        

    $r = round($r/10);
    $g = round($g/10);
    $b = round($b/10);

   // echo "$r , $g, $b <br/>\n";        

    //        $rgb = imagecolorat($im, 4,4);
    //        $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
    //        $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
    //        $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
    //        echo "$r , $g, $b <br/>\n";    

    echo "<div> <img src='images/green.png' border=1 /></div><br/>\n";
    echo '<div style="font-size:60px;color:rgb(' .$r .','.$g.','.$b.')">Text in color of the Image</div>';

    $text = "Text in color of the Image";
    $coloredText = "";
    $j = 0;

    for($i=0; $i<strlen($text); $i++) {
        $coloredText .= '<span style="color:rgb(' .$rarr[$j] .','.$garr[$j].','.$barr[$j].')">'.$text[$i].'</span>';
        $j++;
        if($j === 10) {
            $j=0;
        }
    }

    echo "<div style='font-size:60px;'>$coloredText </div>\n";
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but it doesn't do what I want for some reason. The image I am using is 220x220 and is am image of slate, so it is gray with white mixed in. When I run your code, the image is always gray. I've tried changing the count in the for loops, the number of for loops and the column and row numbers but the result is always text in gray.  The code as show gives a color of 152 , 156, 156 . If I double the samples it becomes 151 , 155, 155. Any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: I edited the answer. I changed the color of each letter of the text according to the each sample from the image. Hope that comes up a little better solution ..

Comment: I tried the last approach and if I increased the sample it did change the color in spots. But I'm looking to make each letter use the image. Ideally, if I could create a transparent image and then fill it in with the background image, it would do what I want, I think. So I changed the code to try to do that but it isn't working. Any ideas? I can't post the code I came up with. Should I open another thread for it?

Comment: I found this page that shows how this is done but the code doesn't work for me and that thread is closed, Can anyone get it to work?   http://www.phpbuilder.com/columns/cash20030526.php3?page=5